# How to access a web application running as a container in ubuntu from my windows system

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, containers

I am running a web application(copied from github examples) that is running as a container in a remote ubuntu VM. The application is a Node JS application that is using mysql database. I brought the application up using docker-compose in ubuntu.

The application came up as http://172....:3000 using a network port. The ip address is displayed in the docker-compose terminal. In the ubuntu system, when i do curl http://172....:3000, it gives a proper success response. The ip address is a container network address. It is not the VM's ip address.  There is no firewall.

How to access the web application from my windows 7 machine. When I tried accessing using http://VM Ip address:3000, it is not hitting ubuntu system. I am not getting any message in the docker-compose terminal. Can anyone help here ?

Comment: is there a firewall on ubuntu?

Comment: Can you add a description of your system layout to the question?  What’s the relationship between the Windows host, an Ubuntu system, the VM, the container, and the 172... IP address?

Comment: Hope I explained better now. There is no firewall in ubuntu. In the docker-compose, I see network-mode, network. Can I use those properties in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the port section in docker-compose, if possible the GitHub project and response of docker ps

Comment: github project : https://github.com/paigen11/mySqlRegistration

You can check the docker-compose.yml under that github project.

Comment: You need to bind your ubunu port to container port.. and expose ubuntu port to internet. then you'll be able to access via http://<ubuntu-ip>:<ubuntu-port>

Answer (score 0):

```
ports:
  - "3031:3000"
```

similar line in your docker compose means you have published port 3000 of your container to port 3031 of your Ubuntu VM.

now you can access your `client` service as `http://<ubuntu-ip>:3031` but before this, you need to allow access to port 3031